# Remove the Theme Cache Hook from Divi Pages Template?

Tags: caching, hook, divi

Ran across sub par programmers using DIVI. Thats garbage. Imagine logging into 4-5 platforms a day to clear cache. How stupid you must be to think that is normal. Qode bridge plus js composer only god in that industry. Have to get rid of yoast also. what a pain from sup par.

Looking to see if there is anyone who knows this hook location quickly. Or can step my time to 10 minutes. If I remove the hook then I can deal with it. Randomly it is only on 7 pages.

```html
<style id="et-builder-module-design-deferred-397-cached-inline-styles"
```

IS THIS CREATING THE OUTPUT OF BELOW -

```html
/**
 * Caches expensive generation of truncate_post content
 *
 * @since 3.17.3
 *
 * @param bool $custom
 * @param string $content
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return string
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'et_divi_truncate_post_use_custom_content' ) ) :
function et_divi_truncate_post_use_custom_content( $custom, $content, $post ) {
    // If post doesn't use builder, no need to compute a custom value
    if ( ! et_pb_is_pagebuilder_used( $post->ID ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $cached = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_et_pb_truncate_post', true );

    if ( $cached ) {
        $cached_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_et_pb_truncate_post_date', true );
        $cached_date = $cached_date ? $cached_date : get_post_field( 'post_modified', $post->ID );
        $global_modules = array();

        $shortcodes = array();
        preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $content, $shortcodes );

        if ( is_array( $shortcodes ) && isset( $shortcodes[3] ) ) {
            foreach ( $shortcodes[3] as $raw_attributes ) {
                $attributes = shortcode_parse_atts( $raw_attributes );
                $attributes = is_array( $attributes ) ? $attributes : array();
                $global_id = (int) et_()->array_get( $attributes, 'global_module', 0 );

                if ( $global_id > 0 ) {
                    $global_modules[] = $global_id;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ( $global_modules as $module_post_id ) {
            // Dates are using the Y-m-d H:i:s format so we can compare them as strings for simplicity.
            if ( strcmp( get_post_field( 'post_modified', $module_post_id ), $cached_date ) > 0 ) {
                // A global module used in the post has been updated more recently than
                // the post's cached excerpt so we need to invalidate the cache.
                $cached = '';
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $cached ) {
        return $cached;
    }

    $custom = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    // Save the result because expensive to compute.
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_et_pb_truncate_post', $custom );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_et_pb_truncate_post_date', date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );

    return $custom;
}
endif;
add_filter( 'et_truncate_post_use_custom_content', 'et_divi_truncate_post_use_custom_content', 10, 3 );
```

THE OUTPUT

```html
<style id="et-builder-module-design-deferred-397-cached-inline-styles">div.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_0{background-image:url(https://samsmovers.com/movers-tampa/sams-movers-holding-hands-new-home.jpg)!important}.et_pb_section_0.et_pb_section{padding-top:0px}.et_pb_row_0.et_pb_row{padding-top:0px!important;margin-top:0px!important;padding-top:0px}.et_pb_divider_0{width:50%}.et_pb_divider_0:before{border-top-color:#77be44;border-top-width:3px}body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_0{color:#ffffff!important;border-color:#77be44;border-radius:0px;background-color:#77be44}body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_1:hover,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_0:hover,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_2:hover{color:#ffffff!important;border-color:#77be44!important;border-radius:0!important;background-image:initial;background-color:#77be44}body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_0:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_2:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_1:after{color:#ffffff}.et_pb_button_0,.et_pb_button_2,.et_pb_button_1{transition:color 300ms ease 0ms,background-color 300ms ease 0ms,border 300ms ease 0ms}.et_pb_button_2,.et_pb_button_2:after,.et_pb_button_1,.et_pb_button_1:after,.et_pb_button_0,.et_pb_button_0:after{transition:all 300ms ease 0ms}.et_pb_image_2,.et_pb_image_0{text-align:left;margin-left:0}.et_pb_section_1.et_pb_section{background-color:#FFFFFF!important}.et_pb_row_9,body #page-container .et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_9.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_9.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single.et_full_width_page #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_9.et_pb_row,.et_pb_row_10,body #page-container .et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_10.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_10.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single.et_full_width_page #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_10.et_pb_row,.et_pb_row_1,body #page-container .et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_1.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_1.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single.et_full_width_page #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_1.et_pb_row{width:90%;max-width:90%}.et_pb_row_1{border:3px solid #000}.et_pb_section_2.et_pb_section{padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;background-color:#335586!important}.et_pb_row_2.et_pb_row{padding-top:0px!important;padding-right:0px!important;padding-bottom:0px!important;padding-left:0px!important;margin-top:0px!important;margin-right:0px!important;margin-bottom:0px!important;margin-left:0px!important;padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px}.et_pb_video_0 .et_pb_video_overlay_hover:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6)}.et_pb_text_4 h1,.et_pb_text_4,.et_pb_text_13,.et_pb_text_12,.et_pb_text_12 h1{text-transform:uppercase}.et_pb_text_5{padding-bottom:20px!important}body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_2,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_1{color:#ffffff!important;border-color:#77be44;border-radius:0px;font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif!important;background-color:#77be44}.et_pb_section_5.et_pb_section,.et_pb_section_3.et_pb_section,.et_pb_section_6.et_pb_section{padding-top:5%;padding-bottom:5%}.et_pb_image_1 .et_pb_image_wrap{border-style:solid}.et_pb_image_1{width:100%;max-width:100%!important;text-align:center}.et_pb_image_1 .et_pb_image_wrap,.et_pb_image_1 img{width:100%}.et_pb_section_4.et_pb_section{background-color:#000000!important}.et_pb_text_13 h4{color:#000000!important;text-align:center}.et_pb_row_8,body #page-container .et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_8.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_8.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single.et_full_width_page #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_8.et_pb_row{max-width:80%}.et_pb_section_8.et_pb_section{background-color:#292929!important}.et_pb_section_9.et_pb_section{padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px}.et_pb_row_11{background-image:url(https://samsmovers.com/wp-content/uploads/areas-served-bg.jpg);background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;overflow:hidden;border-width:3px}.et_pb_row_11.et_pb_row{padding-top:5%!important;padding-right:5%!important;padding-bottom:5%!important;padding-left:5%!important;padding-top:5%;padding-right:5%;padding-bottom:5%;padding-left:5%}.et_pb_row_11,body #page-container .et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_11.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_11.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single.et_full_width_page #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_11.et_pb_row{width:70%;max-width:70%}.et_pb_text_26 h4{text-align:center}.et_pb_column_0,.et_pb_column_4{background-color:#000000;padding-top:5%;padding-right:5%;padding-bottom:5%;padding-left:5%}.et_pb_column_2,.et_pb_column_1{padding-top:5%;padding-right:5%;padding-bottom:5%;padding-left:5%}.et_pb_column_3{background-position:left top;background-image:url(https://samsmovers.com/movers-tampa/sams-movers-blue-jacket-movers-with-box.jpg);padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px}.et_pb_column_19,.et_pb_column_18{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);border-width:3px;border-color:#ffffff;padding-top:5%;padding-right:5%;padding-bottom:5%;padding-left:5%;z-index:9!important;position:relative}.et_pb_column_23{padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px}@media only screen and (min-width:981px){.et_pb_row_2,body #page-container .et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_2.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_2.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single.et_full_width_page #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_2.et_pb_row{width:100%;max-width:100%}}@media only screen and (max-width:980px){body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_0:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_1:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_2:after{display:inline-block;opacity:0}body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_0:hover:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_1:hover:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_2:hover:after{opacity:1}.et_pb_image_0{text-align:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.et_pb_image_0 .et_pb_image_wrap img,.et_pb_image_2 .et_pb_image_wrap img{width:auto}.et_pb_row_2,body #page-container .et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_2.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_2.et_pb_row,body.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.single.et_full_width_page #page-container #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_row_2.et_pb_row{width:100%;max-width:100%}}@media only screen and (max-width:767px){body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_0:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_1:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_2:after{display:inline-block;opacity:0}body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_0:hover:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_1:hover:after,body #page-container .et_pb_section .et_pb_button_2:hover:after{opacity:1}.et_pb_image_0 .et_pb_image_wrap img,.et_pb_image_2 .et_pb_image_wrap img{width:auto}}</style>           <script type="text/javascript" id="wpsp-script-frontend"></script>
```

Comment: in the divi overlay cache php file it states that 397 is crazywebcrawler. But if that is the post ID number then I cannot find anything else that prints inline styles. - To be fair, i like that file but... i would've definitely absolutely put the other columns in another sheet then alphabatized them and copy pasted it over.. but we know that you have to add crap to it

Comment: i did remove the hook from functions php and it did not remove my printed cash line.